# proof of a convergent subrow in every row in B using diagonal argument

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, compactness

> In the space $\ell^1(\Bbb R)=\{x=(x_k)_{k=1}^\infty;x_k\in\Bbb R\text{ and }\|x\|=\sum_{k=1}^\infty|x_k|\}$ consider, for a fixed $y\in\ell^1$, the sets $B=\{x\in\ell^1;\|x\|\le 1\}$ and $M=\{x\in\ell^1;|x_k|\le|y_k|\}$. Find a continuous, real-valued function on $\ell^1$ that does not have a largest value on $B$ and show that $M$ is compact subset of $\ell^1$.

(Copied from [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HSZjq.png).)

I got a hint that for the compactness of M I need to show that every row in B has a convergent subrow (diagonal argument) but I don't know how to show this, does anybody know how to show this?

Comment: Please read the descriptions of tags prior to using them. This is not a harmonic analysis question.

Answer (score 4):

(Getting another question off the unanswered list.)

There are at least four ways to show that the metric space $M$ is compact:

1. Show that $M$ is separable (hence Lindelöf) and countably compact.
2. Show that $M$ is sequentially compact.
3. Show that $M$ is complete and totally bounded.
4. Show that $M$ is homeomorphic to the product space $\prod_{k\in\Bbb Z^+}\big[-|y_k|,|y_k|\big]$, which is compact by the Tikhonov product theorem.

I’ve chosen the first of these, but all of them can be done with a bit of work, and all of them rely on the fact, used twice below, that we can make $\sum_{k>k_0}|y_k|$ as small as we like by taking $k_0$ sufficiently large, thereby leaving only finitely many coordinates with which to deal individually. (Note that this is very much ***not*** the case with $B$.)

To show that $M$ is separable, let

$$M_0=\{\langle x_k:k\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle\in M:x_k\in\Bbb Q\text{ for all }k\in\Bbb Z^+\}\,.$$

For each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ let

$$D_n=\{\langle q_k:k\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle\in M_0:q_k=0\text{ for all }k\ge n\}\,,$$

and let $D=\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb Z^+}D_n\subseteq M$; each $D_n$ is countable, so $D$ is countable. To show that $D$ is dense in $M$ it suffices to show that if $x\in M$, $\epsilon>0$, and $U=\{u\in M:\|x-u\|<\epsilon\}$, then $U\cap D\ne\varnothing$.

There is a $k_0\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $\sum_{k>k_0}|y_k|<\frac\epsilon2$; let $q_k=0$ for each $k>k_0$, and for $k=1,\ldots,k_0$ choose

$$q_k\in\left(x_k-\frac\epsilon{2^{k+1}},x_k+\frac\epsilon{2^{k+1}}\right)\cap\big[-|y_k|,|y_k|\big]\cap\Bbb Q\,.$$

Clearly $q=\langle q_k:k\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle\in D$, and

$$\|q-x\|<\sum_{k=1}^{k_0}\frac\epsilon{2^{k+1}}+\sum_{k>k_0}|y_k|<\sum_{k\ge 1}\frac\epsilon{2^k}=\epsilon\,,$$

so $q\in U\cap D$, as desired, and $M$ is separable and hence Lindelöf, since it’s a metric space.

$M$ is certainly $T_1$, so to show that it is countably compact, we need only show that it is [limit point compact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_point_compact). Let $A=\left\{x^{(n)}:n\in Z^+\right\}$ be an infinite subset of $M$, where $x^{(n)}=\left\langle x^{(n)}_k:k\in\Bbb Z^+\right\rangle$; we’ll show that $A$ has a limit point in $M$.

Let $Z_0=\Bbb Z^+$. The interval $\big[-|y_1|,|y_1|\big]$ is sequentially compact, so there is an infinite $Z_1\subseteq Z_0$ such that $\left\langle x^{(n)}_1:n\in Z_1\right\rangle$ converges to some $u_1\in\big[-|y_1|,|y_1|\big]$. More generally, if $k\in\Bbb Z^+$, and $Z_{k-1}$ is an infinite subset of $\Bbb Z^+$, there is an infinite $Z_k\subseteq Z_{k-1}$ such that $\left\langle x^{(n)}_k:n\in Z_k\right\rangle$ converges to some $u_k\in\big[-|y_k|,|y_k|\big]$, and in this way we recursively construct a point $u=\langle u_k:k\in\Bbb Z^+\rangle\in M$.

To show that $u\in\operatorname{cl}A$, we use the same idea that we just used to show that $D$ is dense in $M$. Let $\epsilon>0$; there is a $k_0\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $\sum_{k>k_0}|y_k|<\frac\epsilon4$. The construction ensures that $\left\langle x^{(n)}_k:n\in Z_{k_0}\right\rangle$ converges to $u_k$ for each $k\in\{1,\ldots,k_0\}$, so there is an $n_0\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that $\left|x^{(n)}_k-u_k\right|<\frac\epsilon{2^{n+1}}$ whenever $n_0\le n\in Z_{k_0}$ and $k\in\{1,\ldots,k_0\}$. Then

$$\begin{align*}
\left\|x^{(n)}-u\right\|&<\sum_{k=1}^{k_0}\frac\epsilon{2^{k+1}}+\sum_{k>k_0}\left|x^{(n)}_k-u_k\right|\\
&\le\sum_{k=1}^{k_0}\frac\epsilon{2^{k+1}}+\sum_{k>k_0}2|y_k|\\
&=\sum_{k\ge 1}\frac\epsilon{2^k}\\
&=\epsilon
\end{align*}$$

whenever $n_0\le n\in Z_{k_0}$, $u\in\operatorname{cl}A$, and $M$ is countably compact.

Finally, a space is compact iff it is Lindelöf and countably compact, so $M$ is compact.

---

For completeness I’ll also answer the first part of the question. It suffices to find a countably infinite closed discrete subset $D=\left\{x^{(n)}:n\in\Bbb N\right\}$ of $B$, define $f_0:D\to\Bbb R:x^{(n)}\mapsto n$, and appeal to the Tietze extension theorem to get a continuous extension $f:\ell^1\to\Bbb R$ of $f_0$ to all of $\ell^1$. However, once one has $D$, it’s actually not hard simply to define such an $f$ explicitly and avoid the appeal to the Tietze theorem.

For $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ let $e^{(n)}=\left(e^{(n)}_k\right)_{k=1}^\infty$, where $e^{(n)}_k=\begin{cases}1,&\text{if }k=n\\0,&\text{otherwise}\end{cases},$ and let $D=\left\{e^{(n)}:n\in\Bbb Z^+\right\}\subseteq B$; clearly $\left\|e^{(n)}-x^{(m)}\right\|=2$ whenever $m\ne n$. For $n\in\Bbb Z^+$ let

$$U_n=B\left(e^{(n)},\frac12\right)=\left\{x\in\ell^1:\left\|x-e^{(n)}\right\|<\frac12\right\}\,.$$

Let

$$f:\ell^1\to\Bbb R:x\mapsto\begin{cases}
2n\left(\frac12-\left\|x-e^{(n)}\right\|\right),&\text{if }x\in U_n\\
0,&\text{if }x\in\ell^1\setminus\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb Z^+}U_n\,;
\end{cases}$$

then $f\left(e^{(n)}\right)=n$ for each $n\in\Bbb Z^+$, so $f$ is unbounded on $B$.

To show that $f$ is continuous, we first show that each point of $\ell^1$ has an open nbhd that meets at most one of the sets $U_n$.

Suppose on the contrary that there are $x\in\ell^1$ and distinct $m,n\in\Bbb Z^+$ such that

$$B\left(x,\frac12\right)\cap U_m\ne\varnothing\ne B\left(x,\frac12\right)\cap U_n\,.$$

Let $y\in B\left(x,\frac12\right)\cap U_m$ and $z\in B\left(x,\frac12\right)\cap U_n$; then

$$\begin{align*}
2&=\left\|e^{(m)}-e^{(n)}\right\|\\
&\le\left\|e^{(m)}-y\right\|+\|y-z\|+\left\|z-e^{(n)}\right\|\\
&\le\left\|e^{(m)}-y\right\|+\|y-x\|+\|x-z\|+\left\|z-e^{(n)}\right\|\\
&<\frac12+\frac12+\frac12+\frac12\\
&=2\,,
\end{align*}$$

which is absurd.

Now we’ll show that $f$ is continuous at each $x\in\ell^1$ and hence on $\ell^1$. Let $x\in\ell^1$; $f$ is clearly continuous at $x$ if there is an $r>0$ such that $B(x,r)\cap\bigcup_{n\in\Bbb N}U_n=\varnothing$, so we may as well assume that there is an $n\in\Bbb N$ such that $B(x,r)\cap U_n\ne\varnothing$ for each $r>0$, i.e., that $x\in\operatorname{cl}U_n$. If $x\in U_n$, then $U_n$ is an open nbhd of $x$, and clearly $f\upharpoonright U_n$ is continuous, so $f$ is continuous at $x$.

If $x\notin U_n$, then $f(x)=0$, and $\left\|x-e^{(n)}\right\|=\frac12$. Let $\epsilon>0$, and suppose without loss of generality that $\epsilon\le 1$, so that $B\left(x,\frac\epsilon{2n}\right)\cap U_m=\varnothing$ for $m\ne n$. Let $y\in B\left(x,\frac\epsilon{2n}\right)$ be arbitrary; then

$$\frac12=\left\|x-e^{(n)}\right\|\le\|x-y\|+\left\|y-e^{(n)}\right\|<\frac\epsilon{2n}+\left\|y-e^{(n)}\right\|\,,$$

so $\frac12-\left\|y-e^{(n)}\right\|<\frac\epsilon{2n}$. Thus, $f(y)<\epsilon$ if $y\in U_n$, and $f(y)=0$ if $y\notin U_n$, so $0\le|f(y)|<\epsilon$ for all $y\in B\left(x,\frac\epsilon{2n}\right)$, and $f$ is continuous at $x$.